# Hibernate persist order

Tags: hibernate

I have a question about how Hibernate persists entity relations.
Let's say I have an entity A that has a relation with entity B and another one with entity C.
I create an A instance and populate it with new instances of B and C. When I persist A I need C to be persisted previous to B. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you need C to be persisted before B? If you don't have any relations or constraints between B and C, I don't see any good reason to rely on a particular order. 1. This would make the code extremely fragile (a refactoring and BANG!). 2. This behavior may differ with another JPA provider (AFAIK there is nothing about this in the JPA spec, this is an implementation detail) and relying on it would harm portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't control the order.

The only thing you can do is call flush on the session after you made the A-C relation and then create the A-B relation. The flush will force hibernate to push new data to the database but will not commit the transaction.

After a flush, the data may or may not be visible to other transactions depending on the database configuration (on mysql for example, there are 4 transaction modes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html).